# No DHCP lease with wlan0

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, dhcp

I am trying to configure `wlan0` on my host. It should be simple, but it's not working :(

In `/etc/network/interfaces`,

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
    wpa-ssid "blahblah"
    wpa-psk "mykey"
```

then I do, `ifconfig wlan0 up`
If I do `ifconfig`, the interface appears
If I do `iwconfig wlan0` I see wlan0 and ESSID:"blahblah" and Access Point: Not associated.
But I think that is normal.

I run `dhclient -v wlan0`
and there I never get the lease :(((

With ifconfig, I also often see an additional interface wlan0:avahi with a dummy IP address 169.254.7.xxx (I'm expecting something like 192.168.100.xxx), and I think this only meand I did not get a DHCP lease.

I ensured that NetworkManager is not running as this seems to be a frequent issue, and it is not.
I have even removed the packages network-manager* from the host

I have also tried to configure the interface with a wpa_supplicant.conf file instead (in `/etc/network/interfaces`) but that does not change anything.

I have restarted the network.

My dhcp soft is isc-dhcp-client v 4.2.4-7

I am running Linux Mint 17 Qiana

Any help appreciated as I am stuck down to typing this on a tablet ;))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit:

So I will show you how to connect to a wifi via CLI: first kill all instances of `dhclient` or `wpa_ANYTHING` that you may have. Then:

```
 pkill dhclient
 pkill wpa_supplicant
 wpa_passphrase "TheNameOfMyNetwork" "MySecretPassword" > wpa.conf
 ip link set dev wlan0 down
 ip addr flush dev wlan0
 ip link set dev wlan0 up
 wpa_supplicant -B -i wlan0 -Dnl80211 -c wpa.conf
 dhclient -v wlan0
```

At this point, you should have a default gateway:

```
 ip route show
     default via 192.168.73.1 dev wlan0 
     192.168.73.0/24 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.73.65
```

If you do not have a default, pls post your routing table **in your original post**, not as a comment: it would be unreadable.

And you should also have some nameserver in `/etc/resolv.conf`. If not,

```
     echo nameserver 8.8.8.8 >> /etc/resolv.conf
     echo nameserver 8.8.4.4 >> /etc/resolv.conf
```

You are ready to surf.

Comment: Hi, thanks but I'm using fvwm, thus with no applet, widget etc. That's also why among other reasons I uninstalled NetworkManager. Can someone please help me troubleshoot the 'manual' configuration for wifi ? should i be setting a route ? gateway , netmask ?... thx

Comment: @user509010 Pls read my Edit.

Comment: YES! It works! Thanks so much! I wonder what was the issue...
By the way, I did not have the n180211 driver, so I used -Dwext instead.

Comment: Thanks. Killing everything at the start is the key.